# EJS comparison between two same strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I try in ejs to compare two Strings which in the current situation are the same and it runs the else case. Here is the code:

```
<% var idf = notifications.data[i].from; %>
<% var ids = notifications.users[a].id; %>
<% if(idf == ids){ %>
    <% index = a; %>
    <script>alert('<%= index %>');</script>
    <% break; %>
<% }else{ %>
    <script>console.log('<%= idf %> - <%= ids %>');</script>
<% } %>
```

It logs 5d5ecfd1ad6d193de86c2264 - 5d5ecfd1ad6d193de86c2264

Answer (score 0):

Use === instead of == to see if this fixes the issue, as it will prevent internal type coercion.

It might also be worth trimming the strings to see if there is any white space or padding added to them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below code to compare two string values in ejs

```
<% if("some text" === "some text"){ %>
<h1>Yes the above text are equal</h1>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing mongoDB objectId, then use toString().

```
<% var idf = notifications.data[i].from; %>
<% var ids = notifications.users[a].id; %>
<% if(idf.toString() == ids.toString()){ %>
    <% index = a; %>
    <script>alert('<%= index %>');</script>
    <% break; %>
<% }else{ %>
    <script>console.log('<%= idf %> - <%= ids %>');</script>
<% } %>
```